# Game event handling system in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, game-engine

I'm building a game and trying to use an event system.
This is the main idea of how it is implemented:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blocker2
{
    public delegate void OnPlayerMoved(PlayerMovedEvent e);
    public delegate void OnPlayerSpawned(PlayerSpawnedEvent e);
    public delegate void OnBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent e);
    public delegate void OnBlockPlaced(BlockPlacedEvent e);

    public static class EventHandler
    {
        private static List<OnPlayerMoved> _onPlayerMoved;
        private static List<OnPlayerSpawned> _onPlayerSpawned;
        private static List<OnBlockBreak> _onBlockBreak;
        private static List<OnBlockPlaced> _onBlockPlaced;


        static EventHandler()
        {

        }

        public static void Subscribe()
        {

        }

        // -------------------------- Player Related Events --------------------------
        public static void OnPlayerMoved(PlayerMovedEvent e)
        {
            foreach (OnPlayerMoved del in _onPlayerMoved)
            {
                del(e);
            }
        }

        public static void OnPlayerSpawned(PlayerSpawnedEvent e)
        {
            foreach (OnPlayerSpawned del in _onPlayerSpawned)
            {
                del(e);
            }
        }

        // -------------------------- Block Related Events --------------------------
        public static void OnBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent e)
        {
            foreach (OnBlockBreak del in _onBlockBreak)
            {
                del(e);
            }
        }

        public static void OnBlockPlaced(BlockPlacedEvent e)
        {
            foreach (OnBlockPlaced del in _onBlockPlaced)
            {
                del(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And there going to be alot more events, and I think this method going to make the code very very complex. There is a better way to do it? (Considering performance and maintability of the code).
Thanks in advanced!
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why not use `event EventHandler<>`? `EventHandler` is a MulticastDelegate so you don't need to maintain your own list.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `event` keyword and using standard C# events?  Also, it's probably not the best idea to allow your events to be publicly fireable from anywhere.  It would be better to have the events within the class that will actually be firing them, so only it is responsible for doing so.

Comment: Why not [`MonoGame`](http://monogame.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CSharpMessenger_Extended

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll move them to a private location, if someone have a generic straight forward tutorial on how to design a system like that using C# please comment or post it as an answer.

Comment: In the end I used events and it was exactly what I was looking for! Though I didnt manage to come up with a solution who doesn't expose the event functions to public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use standard [C# events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)?  They will handle this the same way, since an event allows more than a single subscriber.

The standard event mechanism in C# allows multiple subscribers to subscribe to an event, and would look like:

```
public static event EventHandler<PlayerMovedEventArgs> PlayerMoved;

// Often, you'll have a method to raise the event:
public static void OnPlayerMoved(PlayerMovedEventArgs args)
{
    var handler = PlayerMoved;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(null, args);
}
```

That being said, I would recommend putting these into the class where they are related, and not having them all global/static.  You could then potentially make the method to  raise the event private to that class, which would allow you to keep the design more maintainable.

For example, the `PlayerMoved` event probably would be more appropriate within some class representing your world (or a piece of the world), and in there in a non-static fashion.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! But can you write an example of how exacly I can subscribe additional function to this event? And how to call all of them for each event trigger.

Comment: @UnTraDe The `PlayerMovedEventArgs` is a class that derives from `EventArgs` - you can add anything to it.  The `OnPlayerMoved` shows how to trigger it.  Subscribing is just `PlayerMoved += SomeDelegate` - see the events tutorial I linked for details.